# How to remove a dist-tag in npm?

Tags: npm

Currently learning `npm`.

I have 2 dist-tags, `beta: 1.0.1` & `latest: 1.0.1`.

I want to remove `beta: 1.0.1` & I'm not able to do it.

I tried the following, doesn't work.

```
npm dist-tag rm beta 1.0.1  
npm dist-tag rm beta 
npm dist-tag rm 1.0.1
```

Worst condition, npm docs doesn't have examples on how to remove a dist-tag!

**Edit**: As suggested, gone through the github page. Contributors asking to update `npm`. Still didn't work.

Comment: Docs like this? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag

Comment: @SimonBuchan Yes, that one only.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6243 , relevant to your question.

Comment: @metahost, no examples, contributors asking to update, already updated.

Comment: @Sandeep Roy, what's the output of `npm dist-tag ls`?

Comment: What version of npm are you running? `npm install check-node-version`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/workshopper/how-to-npm/issues/72) `how-to-npm` GitHub issue, you should remove `dist-tag`s like this:

```sh
npm dist-tag rm <module name> beta
```

Where `<module name>` is copied from `"name"` parameter in **`package.json`**:

```json
{
  "name": "@user/exampleNameOfModule", 
                      ^
  ...                 |
                      - copy this, without quotes
},
```

Comment: This should read
```
npm dist-tag rm <module name> beta
```

It does not appear to work if you include a version.

Comment: When removing a tag, do not specify a version.

Answer (score -2):

Try enclosing it in quotes:

`npm dist-tag rm "beta 1.0.1"`