# npm errors when installing react-paypal-button

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install react-paypal-button for a project that I'm working on

but when I do npm install react-paypal-button@2.0.3 I end up getting this error

```html
C:\Users\ryan1\Downloads\Capstone\Ovals>npm install react-paypal-button@2.0.3

> react-paypal-button@2.0.3 preinstall 

C:\Users\ryan1\Downloads\Capstone\Ovals\node_modules\react-paypal-button

> rm -rf dist

'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

npm WARN rollback Rolling back readable-stream@2.3.6 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\ryan1\Downloads\Capstone\Ovals\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-async-script-loader@0.3.0 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! react-paypal-button@2.0.3 preinstall: `rm -rf dist`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the react-paypal-button@2.0.3 preinstall script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
```

If anyone know how to fix it it would be a great helpenter code here

Comment: On Windows machines is really recommend using a real shell with normal Unix-style commands like git bash/cygwin (or whatever its modern-day equivalent is) or at least a set of typical Unix shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this command: `rm -rf dist`.

`'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Follow [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button) to install react-paypal-button.

Also have a look on this as well [dist-tag rm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965289/how-to-remove-a-dist-tag-in-npm)